# How to remove unapproved website domain from Adsense

Tags: wordpress, web, youtube, adsense

I have added a website domain for Adsense monetization. but the site is not eligible for monetization and they gave me two options to submit another review or to try a different domain.
I want to remove this site and I don't want to add a replacement but there is no option for removing this site. by the way, I have already removed the google ads script from my website.
[image: This is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remove an unapproved website from AdSense. answered by AdSense support. The only way is to change the domain or make the current website match the standards.